# Scrapy Request returns wrong currency

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Im trying to scrape [this](https://www.harveynichols.com/int/brand/nars/447215-radiant-creamy-concealer/p2386617/) website for information. Everything is fine except for the price. On the website and in the html the price is listed in USD. But when I run the code below it returns it in GBP.

```
price = response.xpath('//*[@id="page"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/p').extract()
```

I have tried different variations of the following:

```
headers = {
    'USER_AGENT': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36",
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
}
```

```
def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, headers=headers, callback=self.parse, cookies={'hn.globale.currency': 'USD', 'hn.globale.country': 'US'})
```

But its always coming out as GBP. How can I change it to get USD? I can also get the product data as json but its all in GBP there as well.

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Comment: I read the page but I still dont quite know exactly what to do with that. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Could you describe at which part of the process covered in the documentation you got blocked? Maybe we can improve the documentation accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

That page is all built dynamically with Javascript and configured on the fly.  If you look at the page, you'll see the "USD" selection at upper left, but that text is not in the source.  Unless you are executing the Javascript when you scrape, you can't get the conversions.  If they have a JSON API, there must be a way to configure it, but they'd have to tell you that.

Comment: Are you saying that its not possible to change the currency through headers?

Comment: Go look at the page.  There's a tiny bit of HTML and a mountain of Javascript.  The work is all being done in Javascript.  Somewhere in the Javascript, they fill out and populate the currency.  If you're not executing the Javascript, that won't get done.

Comment: So do you know how I can do that?

Comment: Not easily.  Honestly, it would be way easier to look up the current GBP/USD conversion and change the text yourself.

https://www.scrapingbee.com/blog/scrapy-javascript/